# Populate Menu Bar dynamically in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my category name and sub category names stored in a table.

I want to have a layout page(master page) which has a menu bar. I want to pull the category names and subcategory names from the table and display it as a menu and sub menus in my layout page.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need to provide more info, and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have a menu bar in my master page(layout page),and i want to populate the items in it from the db,so far i tried to create a strongly typed view and passed a model containing the category names but i get a compile time error that the model is null.however i am not sure that this approach is correct(can a Master page be strongly typed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that, as far as Im aware, is to use the ViewData. You can do this on every action call (which is not only wrong but also a nightmare) or you can create an abstraction for your controllers and inherit it for every controller. Then in the abstraction itself you will make the database call in the constructor and make sure it is loaded for every action call. [See this for more info](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs)